# How can I create a instance of a class with an array of Strings as the only instance variable?

Tags: java, arrays, string, class

I have written a class Form. An array of 10 Strings is the only parameter in the constructor. How can I create an instance of the class? I'm sure there are other problems in my setters and getters but I cant test them until I fix this.

```
public class FormLab {



public static void main(String[]args){

    Form f1 = new Form(String webForm);

    System.out.println(print(String[] webForm));
    System.out.println("Any Empty Strings? " + f1.getEmptyFields);
    System.out.println("Number of characters in userID? " + f1.getCharNum);
    System.out.println("Do password fields match? " + f1.getPwCheck);
    System.out.println("Does email contain correct characters? " + f1.getEmailCheck);




}
```

}

---

```
public class Form {

String[] webForm = new String[10];

private String userID;
private String pw;
private String pw2;
private String email;
private String name;
private String address;
private String city;
private String state;
private String zip;
private String telephone;

//constructor 
public Form(String[] webForm){


    //filling array with field values
    webForm[0] = "0123456789";
    webForm[1] = "java123";
    webForm[2] = "java123";
    webForm[3] = "luke.skywalker@jedi.com";
    webForm[4] = "Luke Skywalker";
    webForm[5] = "1234 The Force Way";
    webForm[6] = "Rome";
    webForm[7] = "GA";
    webForm[8] = "30161";
    webForm[9] = "7065551234";


}

public boolean getEmptyFields() {
    //boolean empty = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < webForm.length; i++){
        if(webForm[i]!= null){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public String getUserID(){

    return userID;

}

public void setUserId(String userID){
    this.userID = userID;
}

public String getPw(){

    return pw;

}

public void setPw(String pw){
    this.pw = pw;
}

public String getPw2(){

    return pw2;

}

public void setPw2(String pw2){
    this.pw2 = pw2;
}

public String getEmail(){

    return email;

}

public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName(){

    return name;

}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress(){

    return address;

}

public void setAddress(String address){
    this.address = address;
}

public String getCity(){

    return city;

}

public void setCity(String city){
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState(){

    return state;

}

public void setState(String state){
    this.state = state;
}

public String getZip(){

    return userID;

}

public void setZip(String zip){
    this.zip = zip;
}

public String getTelephone(){

    return telephone;

}

public void setTelephone(String telephone){
    this.telephone = telephone;
}

public int getCharNum(String userID) {
    int userLength = 0;

    //userID.length();

    return userLength;

}

public boolean getPwCheck() {
    boolean check = pw.equalsIgnoreCase(pw2);
//  pw.equalsIgnoreCase(pw2);

    return check;

}

public boolean getEmailCheck(String email) {

    if(email.contains("@") && email.contains(".")){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }

public static void getPrint(String[] webForm) {

System.out.println(webForm.toString());

}
```

}

Comment: The Form constructor shouldn't have any argument. It should create its array of 10 elements by itself, instead of forcing all callers to provide an array of 10 elements that the constructor will overwrite. Google for "Java tutorial arrays" to know how to create arrays. Google for "Java tutorial methods" to know how to call methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use method arraycopy.

```
public Form(String[] webForm){
    System.arraycopy(webForm, 0, this.webForm, 0, webForm.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor takes a string array as argument, but you are passing it a string, try:

```
myList = new String[];
myForm = new Form(myList);
```

Comment: he obviously has more issues because the array that's passed in doesn't do anything.... it's useless to pass in an array that does literally nothing. also his constructor parameter causes ambiguity with the global array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your array before putting it as a parameter as follow:

```
 public class FormLab {

 public static void main(String[]args){

      String webForm = new String[10];
      Form f1 = new Form(webForm);

      /*System.out.println(print(String[] webForm)); THIS IS WRONG*/
      /*TO PRINT THE VALUES IN THE ARRAY YOU NEED TO WRITE A METHOD IN UR 
        FORM CLASS THAT WILL LOOP THRU UR VARIABLE AND PRINT*/
      System.out.println("Any Empty Strings? " + f1.getEmptyFields);
      System.out.println("Number of characters in userID? " + f1.getCharNum);
      System.out.println("Do password fields match? " + f1.getPwCheck);
      System.out.println("Does email contain correct characters? " + f1.getEmailCheck); 
}
```

Comment: Why would i need to declare it in the main method when I declared it in the Form class?

Comment: The main method doesn't know anything about the variables u have in ur form class. In ur constructor u r passing an argument therefore u need to pass an argument too in ur class instance in main method. If you wanna use the variable from ur form class then remove the parameter in ur form class constructor

Comment: I have tried all suggestions and still getting error.                                               Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'Labs'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: also: Syntax error on token "]", :: expected after this token

Comment: Actually u r calling methods which need a parameter to execute on a array. So try by just commenting out all the system.out.println and print the values with a for loop